# How to update Name field contents into Title field

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I want to update title field from Name column immediately after file attachment in document library. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use workflow.
I don't know any way in which you can update any column immediately. Attach a workflow the the item creation event.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldnt' it be easier to have the content provider/owner ensure that Title is the same as filename?  Sometimes developing is not the only answer ... collaborate (isn't that what SP is allabout?)